# Adding a CSS class to every form in Drupal 6 in a theme

Tags: forms, theming

I would like to add a class to every form tag that could appear on a page. Because it's strictly for theming purposes, I would like to do that in my custom Drupal 6 theme.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the theme function [theme_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form/6). See [*About overriding themable output*](http://drupal.org/node/173880) for an explanation of how to override theme functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a css class to every form, you loose the point, since you can simple use `form` in your styles.

If you want to do this, you can overwrite the [`theme_form`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form/6), the theme function for forms:

```
THEME_NAME_form($element) {
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'] .= ' extra-class';
  }
  else {
    $element['#attributes']['class'] = 'extra-class';
  }
}
```

Comment: "you loose the point, since you can simple use form in your styles." - that's a good point. This is a temporary solution only; I'm working on converting a CSS framework into a Drupal theme and this framework has several different styles for forms. I want to use one which is available via a class, that's the reason why I'm asking.